# Accidentally deleted the keys in my KeyChain Access and now can't put new ones in

Tags: ios, ios5, keychain

I accidentally deleted the keys in my Keychain Access on my local computer which I use to archive the code when I am ready to submit a new binary.

What I am trying to do to fix this is to go to my IOS PROVISIONING PORTAL, and click on the certificated nav item on the left, and download the dev and production certificates.  I do download them, and then drag them to the KeyChain icon, but I am not sure that is doing anything.

And when I try to archive the code, I get this error:

```
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution: dist_name' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in your keychains
```

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

EDIT:

When I tried to revoke my production certificate, the system said that if I do that, my current live app will no longer work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are countless posts regarding this on S.O. already.

When this happens, your best bet is to begin from SCRATCH. Delete all provisioning profiles and re-do the whole procedure.

Else, you'll be stuck for hours trying to solve problems that may or may not be yours.

Comment: thanks, so is the best thing to do to revoke them in the IOS DEVELOPER SITE? Will doing that let me make new ones?

Comment: It says revoking my production certificate will cause my existing apps to no longer work!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had a simple fix

The distribution key and certificate were missing

I was able to download the certificate but  couldn't get the key

Asked my team member to export his distribution cert and key.

To do that select the key or cert and export(keychain    accesses-> file ->export items-> save on disc).

You will be prompted for the password, remember the password as you need it to extract the files.the files will be saved with extension .p12.

Send the .p12 file to other mac where it needs to be installed

fixed!!

---